# Using @property with getting/setting the lists/arrays: How to properly set an index of the list

Tags: python

Good day!

I would like to use `@property` to get/set an list/array in my code. I would like to access/modify the whole list and, at the same time, its elements. I noticed that when I set the whole list, it utilizes the `@x.setter`-decorated method while when I set an index of a list, it uses the `@property`-decorated method (or the getter; it gets the array first then setting the index). This is a problem since would like to cast the list as an np.array.

So, how do you properly set an index of a list with property?

Below is a sample of my code.

```
import numpy as np

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = [1,2,3]

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        print("getter of x called")
        return np.array(self._x)

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print("setter of x called")
        self._x = value


c = C()
c.x
>>> getter of x called
>>> array([1, 2, 3])
c.x[1]
>>> getter of x called
>>> 2
c.x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> setter of x called
c.x
>>> getter of x called
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
c.x[3] = 6
>>> getter of x called
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: A class can control attribute assignment and item assignment, but it can't control assignment of attributes or items of attributes or items. There is no hook `C` can implement to control assignment of `c.x[3]`.

Comment: Controlling that assignment is the responsibility of whatever object `c.x` evaluates to.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. Will be looking on a solution that permits mutability on `c.x` (well, not casting it to `np.array` allows it to be mutable but..)